# Japanese animated movie (1940s, '50s or '60s?) about boy surrounded by magical beings

Tags: identify-this-movie, anime

A long time ago in a galaxy far away, in the early 1960s I was around 5 or 6. Back in the day, during the day, old movies would be played on the television. There weren't too many channels, but we had cable, so had more than most. I remember being enthralled with a Japanese movie, early Anime, and I've been searching for it for years. Since I remember watching it in the early 1960's, I believe the film could have been made in the 1940's, 1950's or even the very early 1960's. Here's what I remember:

The hero is a young boy. He is surrounded by magical / godlike beings who sometimes take human form. At one point he runs to some docks with a girl. She dives from the dock into the water and turns into a fish. I remember that this scene was dark and stormy. Also, there is an old hag in the film as well.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely, it's ***Panda and the Magic Serpent***, Toei Animation, 1958. The girl turns into a fish, it ends with a storm scene, and, well, the entire thing just *happens* to be on youtube.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panda_and_the_Magic_Serpent):
*Panda and the Magic Serpent* (白蛇伝 Hakujaden?), also known as The Tale of the White Serpent, is the first color anime feature film, released in 1958. It was one of the first three anime films to be released in America, under the title Panda and the Magic Serpent, premiering in 1961, the month after Magic Boy. It is also known variously as Legend of the White Snake, The Great White Snake and The White Snake Enchantress.

Comment: This is it @n_b - and I believe it was called Legend of the White Snake when I saw it. I would never have found it on YouTube without the title. As I watched it again, I remembered it more and more. Thank you!

Comment: @ahavoc You're welcome! Be sure to mark it as the correct answer to help us all out.

Answer (score -1):

Could be this :

Wanpaku Ōji no Orochi Taiji (わんぱく王子の大蛇退治?

From Toei
https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toei_Animation

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.